# How to generate typescript types in supabase cli?

Tags: typescript, supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs).

I am getting stuck at the middleware step, which requires me to use the supabase cli to generate typescript types.

The tutorial contains a link to this [video](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/rest/generating-types) that explains how to make the types. That demo is different to [these docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/rest/generating-types) which are supposed to demonstrate the same thing. I am following the docs, because I cannot locate the equivalent form of address used to identify the project in my project settings file.

When I try using:

```
supabase gen types typescript --project-id myProjectStringIdNoQuotationMarks > @/lib/database.types.ts
```

I get an error that says:

> zsh: no such file or directory: @/lib/database.types.ts

I made a file in the root of my directory called lib/database.types.ts and reran the line, but I get the same error.

Can anyone find a current tutorial showing how to make typescript types in supabase CLI?

This [egghead tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/supabase-generate-typescript-type-definitions-with-the-supabase-cli) suggests that the output file gets created directly when the types are generated.

I tried reinstalling supabase and starting again. This time I get an error that says:

> zsh: command not found: supabase

I can see that supabase is installed in my project.

Comment: here is an explanation to this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77602396/15212313 hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

fyi: i found the answer on reddit. you have to prefix the supabase cli command with 'npx'. maybe its a new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command:

```
npx supabase init
```

If you are using Next.js App Route, navigate to `src/` first, then run the command `npx supabase init`. After that, execute this command: `supabase gen types typescript --project-id myProjectStringIdNoQuotationMarks > lib/database.types.ts`

Good luck!